# not able to view rendered mbtiles and mapbox base map remotely

Tags: server, apache, mapbox, mbtiles

I was able to display the HTML files locally  which displays a base map from mapbox and a layer rendered from tile-stream. I had setup an apache server so that the HTML can be viewed remotely. There is a static domain name, which i was able to access remotely. The port forwarding is given for 80 and tilestream port 8888. On local browser everything is displaying. But on remote system the page loads without base map and layers. I am on ubuntu. The request for the base map base in the HTML file is

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map','examples.map-9ijuk24y');
```

the layer is added with

```
var stamenLayer = L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8888/v2/sample/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking at what firebug shows? Have you tried putting in the real IP address rather than localhost. (Hint: remember that your javascript is running on the client machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to access remotely and without problems your `html` files, then use your `domain name` instead `localhost`:

```
var stamenLayer = L.tileLayer('http://www.mydomain.com:8888/v2/sample/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```